# Admin account no longer accessible on MacBook Pro running El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: performance, administrator, macos

After installing El Capitan, I cannot login to the admin account I was using for the install. I have other admin accounts that work fine, but this was the main one I use with all my important files. I have tried deleting this admin account but the system freezes.  All other accounts work fine.

Any suggestions as to how to access the admin account or how to delete it?